# charter [mathdesign] pdf/a failure glyph width consistency failure

Tags: pdfx, pdf-a, mathdesign

2023 texlive.  A simple pdf file fails a veraPDF validation.  This in itself would not be so bad, except kdp now suddenly no longer accepts my pdf.  could be this, could be some images, don't know yet.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\parindent=0em

\begin{document}

Problem: $\rightarrow$ .

VeraPDF Error: Specification: ISO 19005-1:2005, Clause: 6.3.6, Test number: 1

For every font embedded in a conforming file and used for rendering, the glyph width information in the font dictionary and in the embedded font program shall be consistent.

%% https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-636-1

\end{document}
```

does anyone know whether this is a veraPDF bug or a pdflatex mathdesign font bug?

Comment: well there is a difference and it is large enough to trigger the failure (acrobat reports it too). I don't know if one can correct it by changing the tfm or if one need to change the pfb, but in both case the mathdesign maintainer would have to do something (which probably won't happen).

Comment: hi ulrike --- are there good alternatives?  (maybe for a non-charter font?)

Comment: or, for this matter, is there a way whereby one can "cheat" the font, by copying one of the two glyph widths (ideally the better correct one!) to the other, and calling it mathdesign2 ?